# Why does nginx look for favicon.ico in the wrong place and sends me to the error page?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

I am trying to serve a Vue app which is basically serving static files. I have the simple configuration, which also includes the backend PHP API server.

When I go to `api.myapp.home` (I added it to the `hosts` file), I do see the backend html page. but when I go to `myapp.home`, it sends me to the `50x` error page:

```
user       www-data;

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name api.myapp.home;
        root /var/www/php-backend/public; 
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"; 
        index index.php;
 
        charset utf-8;
 
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }
 
        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
 
        error_page 404 /index.php;
 
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
 
        location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
            deny all;
        }
    }
    
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name myapp.home;
        location /var/www/vue-frontend/dist {
            root   /;
            index  index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }     

}
events {}
```

When going to `myapp.home`, I keep seeing the `index.html` page that's inside `/usr/share/nginx/html;` instead of the Vue `index.html`. Why? the `error.log` at `/var/log/nginx` is showing the following:

[notice]: signal process started
[error]: *53 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: myapp.home, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "myapp.home", referrer: "http://myapp.home/"

But I defined the location as `/var/www/vue-frontend/dist` with root `/`, which is where the `index.html` and `favicon.ico` is. So why does it look for the `favicon.ico` in the error pages location?

Comment: `location /var/www/vue-frontend/dist` matches URLs that begin with `/var/www/vue-frontend/dist` - which does not match the URL `/favicon.ico`. You probably want `location / { root /var/www/vue-frontend/dist; ... }`

Comment: correct! It worked, and if you want you can make it an answer and I will mark it, thank you!